# openSSL: How to create a CAfile

Tags: c, sockets, networking, ssl, openssl

I want the client to send the server a certificate. Now, I'd like to use code that looks like this:

```
   SSL_CTX *ctx;
   STACK_OF(X509_NAME) *cert_names;
   ... 
   cert_names = SSL_load_client_CA_file("/path/to/CAfile.pem");
   if (cert_names != NULL)
       SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list(ctx, cert_names);
   else
       error_handling();
   ...
```

But how do I create a CAfile? Also, if I want to specify only one particular CA, what command do I use to send that?

I've read up on `SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list(SSL_CTX *ctx,STACK_OF(X509_NAME) *list);`, but I don't know how to obtain that `*list` parameter. In this case, I have only 1 single CA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd do something like:

```
SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list(CTX, SSL_load_client_CA_file("/path/to/cacert.crt"));
```

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "how do I create a CAfile". The CA certificate is the public certificate of the certificate authority that has signed the client certificate. Either you signed it (in which case you must be the CA and will have the certificate), or a third party did, in which case it will be in the list of trusted certificates on your system (on Ubuntu, for instance, its in `/etc/ssl/certs`).

Comment: I followed all the steps here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL#SSL_Certificates_for_Server_Use,
And generated a CA, as well as 2 certificates, one for the server and one for the client. Now, I want the client to send the server a certificate, and to do that, I was under the impression I need to have a `certificate list` with my CA's certificate on it, and use the `SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list(ctx, cert_names);` function to insert the CA into the list. How do I make this `certificate list`?

Comment: The code examples I've found seem to pass a certificate.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own self signed CA file by using following command,

`openssl req -out CA.pem -new -x509`

This will generate CA.pem file and private key for the same.

Later you can create cert file and key from the generated CA.pem and private key.

Generate server Cert and key :

`openssl genrsa -out server.key 1024`

`openssl req -key server.key -new -out server.req`

`openssl x509 -req -in server.req -CA CA.pem -CAkey privkey.pem -CAserial file.srl -out server.pem`

similarly you can create cert and key for client.

Comment: Not that I understand what any of these mean, but the last command complains that file.srl does not exist. I used -CAcreateserial instead.